# send JSON Object in ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

i am trying te sent an object in JSON format but the method always get a null object

here is the ERROR :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Source Error: 


Line 15:             context = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
Line 16:             context.Users.Add(user);
Line 17:             if (context.SaveChanges() == 0)
Line 18:             {
Line 19:                 context.Dispose();

Source File: D:\Education\Git\Online-Store-Platform-API\OnlineStorePlatform\OnlineStorePlatform\DBContext\UserContext.cs    Line: 17
```

and that is my code :

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //public UserDTO user;
        public UserContext myContext;
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        //[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register([FromBody]UserDTO user)
        {
            //user = new UserDTO(email, password, userName);
            myContext = new UserContext();
            if (myContext.addUser(new User(user)) == null) return Content("ERROR");
            return Content("Created Successfully");
        }
    }
```

when ever i sent an UserDTO object always get null

my request :

[image: JSON request]

UseDTO class:

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public String email, userName, password;
        public UserDTO(String email, String password, String userName)
        {
            this.email = email;
            this.password = password;
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public UserDTO() { }
    }
```

when i try debugging i got a null object

[image: debugging img]

Comment: for ``email, userName, password`` use properties with getter and setter, like ``public string email{get;set;}``

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public UserContext myContext;

    public AccountController () : this(new UserContext()) {}

    public AccountController (UserContext _myContext) 
    {
       myContext = _myContext;
    }


    // GET: Account
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Register(UserDTO user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
           myContext.Add(User);
          //ToDo: Redirect or many options
        }
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

Edit:

This is important

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public String email { get; set; }
    public String userName  { get; set; }
    public String password  { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: tried but still doesn't work plz look at the edittion

Comment: Properties are required.

Answer (score 0):

Convert email, username and password to property.

public string Email { get; set;}

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found the solution to my problem..
the problem is that i am inherting from class Controller but i should inhert from ApiController .

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        ........
    }
```

it worked after that.. thank you all